# Node/Express: No download on stream.pipe()

Tags: node.js, express, download, streaming

Is there any way to force download when i pipe stream to response?
If I look into Chrome tools, I see that response is OK, with fine headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 20:22:51 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 vegur
Request Headers
view source
```

I even see the pdf file code in detailed response, but no file download is initiated. Maybe I miss something?

My code on route looks like:

```
router.post('/reports/create', access.Regular, function (req, res, next) {
    ...

    pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=some_file.pdf',
            'Content-Length': buffer.length
        });
        res.end(buffer)
    });
});
```

Comment: What's your code? How are you connecting to the server?

Comment: I use usual express pattern `app.post(...)` like in comment below

Comment: I mean, how do you connect in the browser? Are you using something like `XMLHttpRequest`, `$.ajax` or `fetch` to make your request?

Comment: Polymer iron-form (actually it's similar to XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: I think what @Frxmstrem was getting at is, you should include as much of your client request code as possible so people can better answer the question.

Comment: I use Polymer, so there is no much code)) I want to download file on form submit

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) Header to signal to the browser that there is content attached that needs to be downloaded.

```
app.get('/:filename', (req, res) => {
  // Do whatever work to retrieve file and contents      

  // Set Content-Disposition Header on the response
  // filename is the name of the file the browser needs to download when 
  // receiving  the response to this particular request
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${req.params.filename}`);

  // stream the fileContent back to the requester
  return res.end(fileContent)
});
```

Comment: I have stream or buffer, not a certain file

Comment: @AlexNasonov, in my example, fileContent is a stream or a buffer, the main point though of the example is that you're lacking a `Content-Disposition` header in your response. Basically, that header tells the browser that you've returned a stream/buffer of the data and it should be downloaded with the name inside the `filename` value of the header.

Comment: ```router.post('/reports/create', access.Regular, function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=file.pdf`);
...
    pdf.create(html, options).toStream(function(err, stream){
        stream.pipe(res);
    });
});``` - the same problem - I see data in response through console, but the file doesn't download

Comment: Even simple code like: ```res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/txt',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=some_file.txt'
    });
    var buffer =  Buffer.from('string');
    res.end(buffer);``` doesnt work fine((

Answer (score 0):

it works for me like this:

```
var html = '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
let options = {
   format: 'Letter',
   border: '1cm'
};
pdf.create(html, options).toBuffer(function (err, Buffer) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
            data: 'error PDF'
            })
        } else {
            res.set({
                'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.pdf',
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8'
            });
            res.write(Buffer);
            res.end();
        }
    });
```